# Is there a Regex that allows alphabets and max 3 characters (space, period, comma) after an alphabet or some alphabets?

Tags: regex

I know someone may have tried answering this in the past, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I want to write a regex that must start with some alphabet/alphabets and it only allows alphabets and 3 special characters (comma, period, space).
But the catch is, **it should only allow one occurrence of these characters after the alphabet/alphabets**.

So for example,

- "John,. "
- "John .,"
- "John ."
- "John ,"
- "John "
- "John,. Joe, ."

These are acceptable.

But,

- "John,.."      *// has 2 periods*
- "John.,."      *// has 2 periods*
- "John,.,.,. "  *// has more than one occurrence of period and comma*
- ",. John"      *// starts with a character*
- "John , ."     *// has 2 spaces*

These are not acceptable.

I've tried a bunch of regex expressions but none of them can ensure 1 occurence of each character after some text.

This is the regex I've gotten so far but it doesn't allow "John.," or "John,.John"

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+([,.\s](?![,.\s]))?[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:([., ])(?![., ]*\1)){0,3})+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2y3rK/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group #1

  - `[a-zA-Z]+`:
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group #2

    - `([., ])`: Match `,` or `.` or space in capture group #1
    - `(?![., ]*\1)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a repeat of the character matched in capture group #1
  - `){0,3}`: End non-capture group #2. Repeat this group 0 to 3 times
- `)+`: End non-capture group #1. Repeat this group 1+ times
- `$`: End

Comment: This does solve the issue of multiple occurrences but it doesn't accept 
"John" or "John,.John"

Comment: Check my updated answer to address those 2 cases as well.